# Symbol for maximum number in a multidimensional array/vector

Tags: notation, normed-spaces

I know that I can use the symbol "$\max_{1\leq i \leq N} x_i$" to find the max value in an array with one dimension.

What is the symbol to represent a function to find the max value in an array with two dimensions?

Comment: Maybe $\max \{a_{ij}:\, 1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m\}$?

Comment: Or if you prefer $$\max_{\begin{smallmatrix} 1\leq i\leq n \\ 1\leq j\leq m \end{smallmatrix}} x_{ij}$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm